# pass reflected enum to method.invoke java

Tags: java, reflection, enums, methods, invoke

If you have an enum that you are accessing via reflection how would you pass it's value into method.invoke call.

Would it be something like (shown as a static method for simplicity)

```
    Class enumClazz = Class.forName("mypkg.MyEnum",true,MyClassLoader);
    Class myReflectedClazz = Class.forName("mypkg.MyClass",true,MyClassLoader);
    Field f = enumClazz.getField("MyEnumValue");

    Method m = myReflectedClazz.getMethod("myMethod",enumClazz);
    m.invoke(null,f.get(null));
```

Comment: I doubt it - it wonj't compile

Comment: Correct, I had not tried it, the f.get() is invalid, it should have been f.get(null). After correction my example does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably do:

```
Enum e = Enum.valueOf(enumClazz, "MyEnumValue");
```

You will get **unchecked** warnings as you are using raw types but this will compile and run.

Using reflection, you would need to pass an instance to access a `Field` - however in the case of static methods, you can pass in `null` to `Field`'s `get` method as follows:

```
m.invoke(null,f.get(null));
```

Also - is `myMethod` a `static` method as you are calling this with no instance as well?

Comment: He was using the field to try and get enum value. With your code it should be `m.invoke(null, e)`

Comment: @ChssPly76 - I think you need to read my answer again. There's nowt wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

You have an enum definition:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    MY_SAMPLE_ENUM
}
```

And a class which has a method that has an enum parameter:

```
public class SampleClass {
    public static void myMethod(MyEnum myEnumParam) {
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

Invoke `SampleClass.myMethod(MyEnum.MY_SAMPLE_ENUM)` by reflection:

```
Class clazzMyEnum= Class.forName("mypkg.MyEnum", true, myClassLoader);
Enum enum_MY_SAMPLE_ENUM = Enum.valueOf(clazzMyEnum, "MY_SAMPLE_ENUM");

Class clazzSampleClass = Class.forName("mypkg.SampleClass", true, myClassLoader);
Method methodMyMethod = clazzSampleClass.getMethod("myMethod", clazzMyEnum);
methodMyMethod.invoke(null, enum_MY_SAMPLE_ENUM);
```